# Cron not running even after re-configuring

Tags: database, magento-enterprise, cron, crontab

I have an extension that I use for feeding information to an ftp. this extension uses cron to send the feed to the ftp. but now the problem is that there is no heartbeat detected and the crons are not running in magento. I performed the tasks below trying to solve the issue of crons not running.

**1**) I noticed crontab e was not set (linux:ubuntu). i tried to set it to run in every minute

```
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
# 
# m h  dom mon dow   command

* * * * * /bin/sh /var/www/magento/cron.sh
* * * * * /bin/sh /var/www/magento/cron.php
```

**2**) I did a `sudo service cron restart`

**3**) I went to magento admin under `System > Configuration > ADVANCED > System > Cron (Scheduled Tasks) - all the times are in minutes` and Changed this to generate a schedule every minute and I schedule ahead for 5 minutes.

**4**) The I decided to check the cron_schedule table (`select job_code, executed_at, scheduled_at from cron_schedule;`). But still there was not new schedule created.

**5**) I then went to check the `syslog` and I did a `grep CRON` then below are the results

```
Sep  8 17:00:01 mthe-InventSupport02 CRON[18107]: (mthe) CMD (/bin/sh /var/www/magento/cron.php)
Sep  8 17:00:01 mthe-InventSupport02 CRON[18110]: (mthe) CMD (/bin/sh /var/www/magento/cron.sh)
```

After performing the tasks above. The cron were not seem to be running. Is there maybe something I am missing in the setup?

Kind Regards
Mthe

Answer (score 0):

you can not run php file with `sh` command like above try as below in your crontab

`* * * * * php -f /var/www/magento/cron.php`

try and let me know its working or not